# Orbit of left coset group action

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

I have completed parts (i), (iii).

I need help on part (ii).

I know the definition of an general orbit: $Orb_G(x) = \{y\in X\ |\ \exists\ g \in G$ with $g.x =y\}$ But not sure how to show there is only one orbit.

For (iv) Why is the kernel normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (ii), to show that there is a single orbit in the action of $G$ on $X$ is to show that every two elements of $X$ are equivalent with respect to this action. So, given two cosets $xH$ and $yH$ in $X$, can you find a $g$ in $G$ such that $g\cdot xH = yH$?

For (iv), just note that all kernels of homomorphisms are normal, and that an action of $G$ on a set $X$ is just a homomorphism $G \to \text{Sym}(X)$. Presumably (since you didn't ask) you've already shown that this kernel is contained in $H$ (which follows from the fact that if $g\cdot xH = xH$ for all cosets, then, in particular, $gH = H$, so $g \in H$).

Comment: I had $K=\cap_{x \in G} xHx^{-1}$ then let $x=1$. So I got K is a subgroup of H.

Answer (score 2):

Given any $xH\in X$, we have an action of $x^{-1}$ by
$$x^{-1}xH=H$$
so every coset is in the same orbit as $H$.

Comment: So $Orb_G(H)=X$?

Comment: But why can you take an action of $x^{-1}$

Comment: @George He is making the element $\;x^{-1}\in G\;$ act on the left coset $\;xH\;$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $yH$ is another coset. Choose $g= y \cdot x^{-1} \in G$. Then
$g \cdot xH = (g \cdot x) H = (y \cdot x^{-1} x) H =yH$.

If $G$ is **any** group action, then the kernel is
$K = \{g \in G | g \cdot x = x \ \forall x \in X \}$.

Suppose $g_1, g_2 \in K$ and $x \in X$, then
$(g_1 g_2) \cdot x = g_1 \cdot (g_2 \cdot x) = g_1 \cdot x = x$ and
similarly for $(g_2 g_1) \cdot x = x$, and so $(g_1 g_2) \cdot x = (g_2 g_1) \cdot x$. Since this is true for all $x$ we have $g_1 g_2 = g_2 g_1$.